# XLookup function won't detect an exact match until I place the cell in edit mode and then exit

Tags: excel, vba, excel-365, xlookup

I am using the XLookup function in Excel 365.  I use a VBA script to create an ID number for a row of data and then I place that ID number into a cell.

If I use the XLookup function with Exact Match to locate that ID number and give me some value in a column next to it, I get an N/A.

However, if I manually locate that exact ID number and place the cell in edit mode and then exit the cell without taking any other step to alter the data in any way, the XLookup function returns the correct result.

[image]

If I leave the cell in it's initial state but use the Match Mode "-1" to get an exact match or next smaller, it returns the correct result.  I don't want to leave it in that mode, because my final function will be two nested Xlookup functions that check one table for the ID and if not there, looks at an alternate table, so I don't want the first function to return a "next smaller" result.

When I generate the ID number in the VBA script, I generate it as the type "Variant" because the ID number is a decimal, such as 210.1. I then simply set that cell's Value to the variant ID number.

Here is a how I place the data into the cell:

```vb
Dim myID As Variant
Dim myCell As Variant
Dim myRange As Range

Set myRange = Range(someNamedRange)

myID = GenerateNextID 'This generates a variant in the form of something like 201.1

For Each myCell In myRange

    myCell.Value = myID
    myID = myID + 0.1

Next myCell
```

Excel seems to recognize it as a number; at least I seem to be able to do math functions on the ID number and get correct results.

I tried putting the lookup ID number in quotes to see if looking it up as text instead of a number produced a different result, but it didn't change my result.

Why am I getting this result? Is there a way to resolve it without using a different Match Mode?

Comment: might help to show us the code that places the ID in the cell

Comment: @chrisneilsen added a code sample

Comment: calculation is in manual mode ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a floating point precision error. The value in E11 is 211.39999999999998 rather than 211.4. Excel corrects the error when you re-enter the cell's value.

Write the value using a line like:

```
myID = Round(myID + 0.1, 1)
```

Comment: I tired adding the change you suggested, but it didn't change my result.  I would have been surprised if it had since I started with a whole number and only incremented by 0.1.  I'm able to select the cell and extend the floating point precision to multiple decimal places and it shows 211.400000

Comment: The value only looks like 211.4. Excel has actually stored 211.39999999999998, which doesn't exactly match 211.4, so the XLOOKUP fails.
I copied your VBA to replicate the issue. With my change, the formula works. I assume you have something else going on as well.

Comment: you were right!  Thank you! Once the ID is generated it gets put into one location, but that record gets moved into an array and placed back into a different range on another sheet.  So I re-tested your code on the original data and the rounding corrected the problem. I assumed that since it had been rounded, when I placed it into an array and then moved it to another location, it wouldn't have added the rounding error back; looks like it did.  So it looks like I need to correct the rounding error each time a transaction gets moved...annoying, but at least that solves the problem.

Comment: Once you recognize that floating point precision errors can occur, you'll tend to spot them everywhere. Incrementing non-integer values will cause errors, sooner-or-later, as will simple math. For example: =((0.5-0.4)-0.1)*1 should equal zero, but it actually equals -2.7756E-17. Often the errors remain hidden, until we do things like exact matches. As a general rule, never do exact matches on raw values.